# How can I have kde/kwin slide the desktop background together with the windows when switching desktops (while using the slide effect for switching)?

Tags: kde, kde-4, kwin

How can I have kde/kwin slide the desktop background together with the windows when switching desktops (while using the slide effect for switching)?

At the moment, it only slides the windows while leaving the desktop background stationary, which is quite disorienting to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Settings -> Virtual Desktops -> Virtual Desktops -> Different widgets for each desktop: on

*It appears this is no longer supported in Plasma 5.2 (kubuntu 15.04):
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/2u2r7e/plasma_52_different_widgets_for_each_virtual/*